# C - initialize wchar_t array within global struct

Tags: arrays, c, struct, initialization, wchar-t

My goal is to have a `default_game_data.h` and a `default_game_data.c` where I can store, for example, some default weapon data to load, when the player changes weapons.

default_game_data.h:

```c
typedef struct weapon
{
    wchar_t name[30];
    int  damage;
    int  agility_modify;
}weapon;


const extern weapon sword;
```

default_game_data.c:

```c
#include "default_game_data.h"

const weapon sword = {
    .name = {L'S',L'w',L'o',L'r',L'd',L'\0'},
    .agility_modify = 0,
    .damage = 5
};
```

This is the only way I could compile without this error:

```
integer conversion resulted in truncation
C/C++(69) 
 wchar_t [10]{(error-type)error-constant}
```

But initializing the array wchar-by-wchar is pretty annoying to maintain, and as soon as I try like `.name = L"Sword"`, I got this error above.

Does anyone know how to assign a `wchar_t[]` the same way like a `char[]`?
Or, maybe there is a better method of storing such data? It should be central and editable.

For a short experiment, I try a `char[]` and `wchar_t[]` example:

```
typedef struct c_human {
    char f_name[10];
    char *s_name;
}c_human;

c_human human1 = {
    .f_name = "Peter",
    .s_name = "Hagen"
};

typedef struct w_human {
    wchar_t f_name[10];
    wchar_t *s_name;
}w_human;

w_human human2 = {
    .f_name = L"Peter",
    .s_name = L"Hagen"
};

w_human human3 = {
    .f_name = {L'P',L'e',L't',L'e',L'r',L'\0'},
    .s_name = L"Hagen"
};
```

Assigning `.s_name` via pointer always works out, but I think it overflows the storage beyond.

Assigning `human1.f_name` works with `= "Peter"`, but assigning `human2.f_name` with `= L"Peter"` does not.

Comment: What platform, compiler and compiler flags are you using?  `.name = { L"Sword" },` [compiles](https://wandbox.org/permlink/pslE4mCOmpBU9bKI) for me.

Comment: @PaulSanders gcc23 on ubuntu linux x64 and vs-code as editor. Maybe my project is wrong configured :/

Comment: What's gcc23?  The latest version of GCC is 13.1.

Comment: @JohnBollinger sorry i mean gnu23 standard and the gcc 11.3.0 compiler.

Answer (score 1):

> Does anyone knows how to assign a wchar_t[] the same way like a char[]?

It's important to distinguish between *assigning* and *initializing*.  Your examples deal with the latter, not the former, and the rules for these are not the same.  In particular, you cannot assign to whole arrays at all.

But you *can* initialize `wchar_t` arrays with wide string literals, in every version of standard C.  C23 puts it this way:

> An array with element type compatible with a qualified or unqualified version of `wchar_t`, `char16_t`,
> or `char32_t` may be initialized by a wide string literal with the corresponding encoding prefix (`L`,
> `u`, or `U`, respectively), optionally enclosed in braces. Successive wide characters of the wide string
> literal (including the terminating null wide character if there is room or if the array is of unknown
> size) initialize the elements of the array.

(C23 6.7.10/16)

That's closely analogous to the provisions for initializing a `char[]` with an ordinary string literal.  In particular, this:

```
const weapon sword = {
    .name = L"Sword",
    .agility_modify = 0,
    .damage = 5
};
```

and this:

```
const weapon sword = {
    .name = { L"Sword" },
    .agility_modify = 0,
    .damage = 5
};
```

conform to every version of C from C89 through C23, given the definition of `weapon` provided in the question.  And my compiler (GCC 8.5.0) accepts both without any complaint.

---

With respect to your second set of examples, you say

> Assigning `.s_name` via pointer always works out, but I think it overflows the storage beyond.

I see no reason to think that that would overflow in any of the cases presented.

And I see no reason to expect that a conforming C compiler would reject ...

> ```
> w_human human2 = {
>     .f_name = L"Peter",
>     .s_name = L"Hagen"
> };
> ```

If your compiler is rejecting that (in the context of the given definition for `w_human`), then I would attribute that to a compiler bug.

Comment: Okey thank you very much. I still have a lot to learn. 
Now I'm almost sure that my error detection/intelliSense is configured incorrectly.

Does wchar_t name* = L"Peter" does not need a dynamic memory allcocation before storing data?

Comment: @ProggerParrot, `wchar_t name* = L"Peter"` initializes `name` to point to the existing, unmodifiable, static array of `wchar_t` represented by the wide string literal `L"Peter"`.  This is is allowed, and does not involve dynamic memory allocation.  Dynamic allocation requires pointer use, but pointer use does not require dynamic allocation.